# CNN Autoencoder with Embedding(300D GloveVec) layer for 10-15 word sentence not working problem due to padding

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

Using pretraining GloveVector from stanford to get the meaningful representation of each word but i want representations for a sentence containing 5-15 words, so that i can make use of cosine similarity to do a match when i receive a new sentence. I am setting a 15 words (fixed size) of each sentence and applied embedding layer then the new input shape is going to be 15 X 300 dimensions (If i have less than 15 words then padded values to make it 15 words (one random uniform distribution of 300D vector)

Below are my network shapes

1. [None, 15] -- Raw inputs embedding and padded(1) ID's
2. [None, 15, 300, 1], --input
3. [None, 8, 150, 128],  -- conv 1
4. [None, 4, 75, 64],  -- conv 2
5. [None, 2, 38, 32], -- conv 3
6. [None, 1, 19, 16], -- conv 4
7. [None, 1, 10, 4] -- conv 5
8. [None, 50] ---------Latent shape (new meaningful representati)------
9. [None, 1, 10, 4] -- encoded input for de-conv
10. [None, 1, 19, 16],   -- conv_trans 5
11. [None, 2, 38, 32],   -- conv_trans 4
12. [None, 4, 75, 64],   -- conv_trans 3
13. [None, 8, 150, 128],  -- conv_trans 2
14. [None, 15, 300, 1]  -- conv_trans 1 -- for loss funtion with input

I have tried the CNN model with embedding layer in tensorflow

```
    self._inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=[None, self.sent_len], name='input_x') #(?,15)
    losses = []
    # lookup layer
    with tf.variable_scope('embedding') as scope:
        self._W_emb = _variable_on_cpu(name='embedding', shape=[self.vocab_size, self.emb_size], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0))
        # assigned pretrained embedding here, so initializer would be overrided
        sent_batch = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=self._W_emb, ids=self._inputs)
        sent_batch = tf.expand_dims(sent_batch, -1)

    self._x = sent_batch
    encoder = []
    shapes = []
    current_input = sent_batch
    shapes.append(current_input.get_shape().as_list())
    for layer_i, n_output in enumerate(n_filters[1:]):
        with tf.variable_scope('Encode_conv-%d' % layer_i) as scope:
            n_input = current_input.get_shape().as_list()[3]
            W, wd = _variable_with_weight_decay('W-%d' % layer_i, shape=[filter_size,filter_size,n_input,n_output],
                                                initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0), wd=self.l2_reg)
            losses.append(wd)
            biases = _variable_on_cpu('bias-%d' % layer_i, shape=[n_output], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.00))
            encoder.append(W)
            output = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(current_input, W, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME'), biases), name=scope.name)
            current_input = output
            shapes.append(output.get_shape().as_list())
    #z = current_input
    original_shape = current_input.get_shape().as_list()
    flatsize = original_shape[1]*original_shape[2]*original_shape[3]
    height,width,channel = original_shape[1]*1,original_shape[2]*1,original_shape[3]*1
    current_input = tf.reshape(current_input,[-1,flatsize])

    with tf.variable_scope('Encode_Z-%d' % layer_i) as scope:
        W_en, wd_en = _variable_with_weight_decay('W', shape=[current_input.get_shape().as_list()[1], outsize],
                                                initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05),
                                                wd=self.l2_reg)
        losses.append(wd_en)
        biases_en = _variable_on_cpu('bias', shape=[outsize],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.00))
        self._z = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(current_input, W_en), biases_en)) # Compressed representation (?,50)

    with tf.variable_scope('Decode_Z-%d' % layer_i) as scope:
        W_dc, wd_dc = _variable_with_weight_decay('W', shape=[self._z.get_shape().as_list()[1], current_input.get_shape().as_list()[1]],
                                        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05), wd=self.l2_reg)
        losses.append(wd_dc)
        biases_dc = _variable_on_cpu('bias', shape=[current_input.get_shape().as_list()[1]],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.00))

        current_input = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(self._z, W_dc), biases_dc))
        current_input = tf.reshape(current_input,[-1,height,width,channel])
    encoder.reverse()
    shapes.reverse()
    for layer_i, shape in enumerate(shapes[1:]):
        with tf.variable_scope('Decode_conv-%d' % layer_i) as scope:
            W = encoder[layer_i]
            b = _variable_on_cpu('bias-%d' % layer_i, shape=[W.get_shape().as_list()[2]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.00))
            hh,ww,cc =  shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]
            output = tf.nn.relu(tf.add( tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(current_input, W, [tf.shape(sent_batch)[0],hh,ww,cc],strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],padding='SAME'), b),name=scope.name)
            current_input = output
    self._y = current_input
    # loss
    with tf.variable_scope('loss') as scope:
        cross_entropy_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(current_input - sent_batch))
        losses.append(cross_entropy_loss)
        self._total_loss = tf.add_n(losses, name='total_loss')

    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001)
    grads = opt.compute_gradients(self._total_loss)
    self._train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads)
```

But the results are not performing well because below two sentence cosine similarity is 0.9895 after getting the latent compressed representation from above model.

1. Functional disorders of polymorphonuclear neutrophils'
2. Unspecified fracture of skull, sequela'

And if i take sentences with 2-5 words and the similarity is going up to 0.9999 (suspecting the issue was caused by more default padding values with same uniform distribution from embedding lookups)

Below information may be helpful,

1. Total of 10,000 training samples with 10 epochs
2. Used Relu activations
3. MSE loss function
4. Adam optimizers
5. Below is the words distributions of over all sentence [[image: 1]]

And finally can anyone suggest what's going wrong? and approach itself is not good to proceed?

Comment: Since this is no software question I'd recommend moving this to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/